# Is it still possible to develop C# software for Ubuntu?

Tags: banshee, c#

I know that in the 2000s a number of popular pieces of software were written in C# for Linux. To list a few:

1. [Begal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_%28software%29)
2. [Banshee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banshee_%28media_player%29)
3. [F-spot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-Spot)
4. [Moonlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moonlight_%28runtime%29)
5. [Moonshine](http://abock.org/moonshine/)

There was also a IDE called Monodevelop. Is it still possible to develop C#, GUI software for Linux? Or is the whole idea of Mono dead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Monodevelop is still actively developed](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop.)

[It's no longer packaged for recent versions of Ubuntu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/monodevelop/)

[You will have to setup their own repo](http://www.monodevelop.com/download/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives)

Though less popular than it used to be IMHO for desktops, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) itself is still actively developed and recently mono on mobile platforms.